# Smooth Edit & Continue in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I would like the Visual Studio to enter the Edit & Continue mode automatically after error is raised, so I do not have to make several clicks on buttons in different windows: first on "Enable Editing" in exception window and then on "Edit" button asking me if I want to do Edit & Continue. Finally, I do not know shortcut for "Continue" button after I have performed the edit.

Comment: @GrantWinney F5 seems to be working now :)

Comment: If you click on the Debug tab it will give you all the shortcuts.  You can also hover the icons in the toolbar and it will tell you their shortcuts, but I have no clue why hovering over "Continue" does not provide the shortcut key, maybe an oversight.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really asked a question here, it's more of a suggestion about what you'd like in the product. I'd suggest you raise the idea on the Visual Studio Uservoice site: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/